# How to read and write A FAT in WinXP

Tags: tasm

I am trying to read the FAT using Int 13H of but its Failing as I run the program. It flashes a message "Access Denied " though I am working in the Administration Domain Can any one answer me the reason and solution for it
Thanking You
Gaurav

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CreateFile` API for Win32 as detailed in this article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100027

Note in Windows Vista direct disk access is restricted further:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx